# if statements give me several warnings what do they mean?

Tags: r, if-statement

```
  fkelly6 = matrix(data = NA, nrow = 252, 3)

    for(i in 1:252){

    fkelly6[i,] = matrix(c(ftmp6[i,],1-sum(ftmp6[i,])),1,3)
    if(fkelly6[i,]>= 15){
      fkelly6[i,]<-15
     }
    }
```

I want check if all the f are >= 15 and in case substitute them with 15.
the code works but it gives me several warnings that say: "In if (fkelly6[i, ] >= 15) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
what do them mean?
thanks

Comment: the error is because in your if you have a vector of length 3 (in this case) and it's compared to a scalar (15), so the condition as length > 1. Basically you have something like c(10, 15, 10) > 15, the if can't work this way.

Comment: so I have to create a vector of length 3 and fill it up with 15?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can change some values without a loop:

```
m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
m
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6

m[m>=4] <- 0 # every value which is >=4 will be set to zero
m
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    0
# [2,]    2    0    0
```